# calling javascript event strings in to native iOS calendar iPHone

Tags: javascript, objective-c, cordova

We have develop iPhone application in phonegap environment. I would like to call the below javascritpt function in Objective-C Xcode to create an event in native iOS calendar.

```
//calendar.js

var calendarPlugin = {
createEvent: function(title, location, notes, startDate, endDate, successCallback, errorCallback) {
    cordova.exec(
        successCallback, // success callback function
        errorCallback, // error callback function
        'CalendarPlugin', // mapped to our native Java class called "CalendarPlugin"
        'addCalendarEntry', // with this action name
        [{                  // and this array of custom arguments to create our entry
            "title": title,
            "description": notes,
            "eventLocation": location,
            "startTimeMillis": startDate.getTime(),
            "endTimeMillis": endDate.getTime()
        }]
    ); 
 }
```

}

I have the basic code of calendar event in objective C, I just need to pass string value from javascript to this calendar event Obj-c method. what to write in below webview method

```
 - (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView*)theWebView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest*)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
```

Comment: I have got some useful solution link. https://github.com/felixactv8/Phonegap-Calendar-Plugin-ios

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure about the calendar part, but this one can help you out.

make sure you already define your plugin in your config.xml

```
<feature name="CustomPlugin">
      <param name="ios-package" value="CustomPlugin" />
</feature>
```

Implementing the plug-in by using Objective-C code

CustomPlugin.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <Cordova/CDV.h>

@interface CustomPlugin : CDVPlugin

- (void)sayHello:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand*)command;

@end
```

CustomPlugin.m

```
#import "CustomPlugin.h"

    @implementation CustomPlugin

    - (void)sayHello:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand*)command{

        NSString *responseString =
            [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Hello World, %@", [command.arguments objectAtIndex:0]];

        CDVPluginResult *pluginResult =
            [CDVPluginResult resultWithStatus:CDVCommandStatus_OK messageAsString:responseString];

        [self.commandDelegate sendPluginResult:pluginResult callbackId:command.callbackId];
    }

    @end
```

Calling a plug-in from JavaScript

```
function initial(){
    var name = $("#NameInput").val();
    cordova.exec(sayHelloSuccess, sayHelloFailure, "CustomPlugin", "sayHello", [name]);
}

function sayHelloSuccess(data){
    alert("OK: " + data);
}

function sayHelloFailure(data){
    alert("FAIL: " + data);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much Friend. Your answer is almost correct. Though I have followed this link "https://github.com/felixactv8/Phonegap-Calendar-Plugin-ios" to resolve.